# Travis CI build failed in gradle task

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I've create an extra task in my build.gradle to provide secret keys for public github repo.

```
afterEvaluate {
initFabricPropertiesIfNeeded()
}
def initFabricPropertiesIfNeeded() {
def propertiesFile = file('fabric.properties')
if (!propertiesFile.exists()) {
    def commentMessage = "This is autogenerated fabric property from system environment to prevent key to be committed to source control."
    ant.propertyfile(file: "fabric.properties", comment: commentMessage) {
        entry(key: "apiSecret", value: FABRIC_API_SECRET)
        entry(key: "apiKey", value: FABRIC_API_KEY)
    }
}}
```

I want to build this with travis ci server side and add these two variables FABRIC_API_SECRET and FABRIC_API_KEY in environment variables settings.

But the build failed with this exception.

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not find property 'FABRIC_API_SECRET' on project ':app'.

Any ideas how can I solve this ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set these environment variable values in your Travis CI settings panel you should be able to access the environment values with gradle using:

```
 entry(key: "apiSecret", value: "$System.env.FABRIC_API_SECRET")
 entry(key: "apiKey", value: "$System.env.FABRIC_API_KEY")
```

The reason for the error is that gradle thinks you are invoking a property value and not accessing a string.

Comment: Glad to be able to help with the gradle build file